# Pass parameters to template without overriding data context

Tags: meteor

I want to pass a new parameter to a template with keeping it's original data context.

- original data context : {message:"hello"}

  `{{> myTemplate withIcon=True}}`
- data context is overriden with {withIcon:True}

Acually my solution is to wrap data like this.

```
<code>
{{> myTemplate originalData=this withIcon=True}}
</code>
```

Is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always extend the current context in a helper:

```js
Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
  iconContext: function() {
    var result = _.clone(this);
    result.withIcon = true;
    return result;
  }
});
```

And use it like this:

```html
<template name="parentTemplate">
  {{> myTemplate iconContext}}
</template>
```

Alternatively, you could create a more generic helper like this:

```js
Template.registerHelper('extendContext', function(key, value) {
  var result = _.clone(this);
  result[key] = value;
  return result;
});
```

And then choose the key/value pairs from within the html of any template:

```html
<template name="parentTemplate">
  {{> myTemplate extendContext 'withIcon' true}}
  {{> myTemplate extendContext 'isAwesome' false}}
</template>
```

Either solution is more desirable than hiding the original data in a separate field, as it keeps the child template generic.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Why do you nee to do _.clone(this)?

Comment: Why do you nee to do _.clone(this)? What if I add result to a child data context? Something like iconContext : function(childDataLikeMsgPost) {... childDataLikeMsgPost.withIcon=...} That would help me a lot

Answer (score 7):

Building on [David's second option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28019575/2055760) to allow for multiple attributes:

```
<template name="parentTemplate">
  {{> myTemplate extendContext withIcon=true label="Has Icon" }}
  {{> myTemplate extendContext withIcon=false label="No Icon" }}
</template>
```

and then in javascript:

```
Template.registerHelper('extendContext', function(data) {
  var result = _.clone(this);
  _.each(data.hash, function(value, key) {
    result[key] = value;
  })
  return result;
})
```

Comment: That should work as well: `return _.extend({}, this, data.hash);`