# In Spacebars, can you combine an inclusion argument with a data object?

Tags: meteor

This is something I've come across a few times. I'd like to do

```
{{> subtemplate item foo="bar"}}
```

So that the data context in `subtemplate` has all the item fields plus a `foo` field. Don't see any way to do this in the docs

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md

I know I could make my own helper `combine` to use like this: `{{> subtemplate combine item "foo" "bar"}}`, but am hoping there's a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass parameters to template without overriding data context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015971/pass-parameters-to-template-without-overriding-data-context)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use dynamic template to pass in your data context?

```
 {{> Template.dynamic template=template [data=data] }}
```

See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic

Comment: `Template.dynamic` is used for dynamic templates, it does not introduce any new feature to the data context.

Comment: You still need to write your own helpers to pass the data context into the dynamic template, so it will be like `{{> Template.dynamic template=template data=getMyData }}` and the helper will be `Template.getMyData.helpers({
getMyData: function(item) {
 item.foo = 'bar';
return item
}
})`