# Passing multiple parameters between templates in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a parent and a child template. I want to pass the data context and couple of other parameters from parent to child.
So far the below code is not working

```
<template name='parent'>
  {{#each arrayFromHelper}}
     {{> child this groupName='biggroup'}}
  {{/each}} 
</template>

<template name='child'>
 {{this}}
 {{groupName}} 
</template>
```

i am not being able to access the groupName in child template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a two options:

**rename the context and add more variables**

```
{{> child data=this groupName='biggroup'}}
```

Now `child` has access to both the parent context and the `groupName`. The only trick is that you'll need to access the context via the `data` namespace (or whatever you choose to call it) which may seem a little verbose.

```
<template name='child'>
 {{data.someValue}}
 {{groupName}}
</template>
```

**extend the context in a helper**

Add a helper to the parent template which extends its context like this:

```js
Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
  context: function() {
    var result = _.clone(this);
    result.groupName = 'biggroup';
    return result;
  }
});
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
{{> child context}}
```

The `child` template will then have the parent context along with the `groupName`. This is the technique I prefer whenever possible.

Also see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015971/pass-parameters-to-template-without-overriding-data-context) if you'd prefer to do this with a global helper.