# Passing variables into Meteor templates and using said variables in handlebar if statements

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am trying to pass a variable into a Meteor.js template and then use the variable in an if statement (in said template). One solution I could do is to simply use three separate templates rather than divide one template up using if statements, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to execute this. I know you can't use {{}} inside other {{}}'s, and handlebar if statements also don't seem to handle equality comparisons.

Here's my code (**idType** is the variable I'm passing through):

```
<template name="license">
    {{> idForm idType="license"}}
</template>

<template name="idForm">
    <form class="idForm">
        {{#if idType=="license"}}
            <span>Driver's License Details</span>
            <input type="text" id="su-licenseNo" placeholder="License Number" />
            <input type="text" id="su-surname" placeholder="Surname" />
            <input type="text" id="su-givenNames" placeholder="Given Names" />
            <input type="text" id="su-dateOfIssue" placeholder="Date Of Issue" />
            <input type="text" id="su-dateOfExpiry" placeholder="Date Of Expiry" />
            <input type="text" id="su-height" placeholder="Height" />
        {{/if}}

        {{#if idType=="passport"}}
            <span>Passport Details</span>
            <input type="text" id="su-type" placeholder="Type" />
            <input type="text" id="su-issuingCountry" placeholder="Issuing Country" />
            <input type="text" id="su-passportNo" placeholder="Passport Number" />
            <input type="text" id="su-surname" placeholder="Surname" />
            <input type="text" id="su-givenNames" placeholder="Given Names" />
            <input type="text" id="su-nationality" placeholder="Nationality" />
            <input type="text" id="su-dateOfIssue" placeholder="Date Of Issue" />
            <input type="text" id="su-dateOfExpiry" placeholder="Date Of Expiry" />
        {{/if}}

        {{#if idType=="sin"}}
            <span>SIN Details</span>
            <input type="text" id="su-surname" placeholder="Surname" />
            <input type="text" id="su-givenNames" placeholder="Given Names" />
            <input type="text" id="su-number" placeholder="SIN" />
        {{/if}}

        <button>Submit!</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the comparison in the `{{#if ...}}` handlebar statements, `{{#if idType=="license"}}` isn't valid handlebars syntax.

You can get around this by making a [comparison helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional) or you can alter your usage slightly and do:

```
<template name="license">
  {{> idForm isLicense=1}}
</template>

<template name="idForm">
  <form class="idForm">
    {{#if isLicense}}
      ...
    {{/if}}
    {{#if isPassport}} <!-- this will be false since it was omitted -->
      ...
    {{/if}}
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Good idea! I'll most likely go with this method. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I've just run into an issue using this method--when I add the variable isLicense into the template call, it overwrites all the other variables that are being initialized via the helper (all of the returned objects are blank). Any ideas?

Comment: You'd have to post your helper code. Also don't know the data context your helpers are operating on. Check in your helpers that *this* is correct. [Docs on hash arguments](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#hash-arguments)

Comment: Yes, it turned out I was overwriting the data context. I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015971/pass-parameters-to-template-without-overriding-data-context. Thanks for your help.