# Passing @index to child template Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to know how to pass the new @index variable to a child template in Meteor 1.2. 
I've got something like:

```
    {{#each scores}}
          {{@index}} //<---- THIS WORK
        {{> scoreItem}}
    {{/each}}

    <template name="scoreItem">
            <div class="position">
                {{@index}}. // <----- GIVE ERROR
            </div>
    </template>
```

I get always undefined or an error

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you share, what kind of error is raised?

Answer (score 2):

For purposes of demonstration, I'm going to assume a score has a `value` property.

### Option 1: pass `index` as part of the context

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each scores}}
    {{> scoreItem score=this index=@index}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="scoreItem">
  <div>{{score.value}} {{index}}</div>
</template>
```

### Option 2: extend the context with `index`

This solution is similar to my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015971/pass-parameters-to-template-without-overriding-data-context):

```js
Template.registerHelper('extendContext', function(key, value) {
  var result = _.clone(this);
  result[key] = value;
  return result;
});
```

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each scores}}
    {{> scoreItem extendContext 'index' @index}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="scoreItem">
  <div>{{value}} {{index}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I thought there was a more direct way of accessing the index inside a template - but your two methods seem to  be the only ones that work